# SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA does not showing any record

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying the below query against SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA from account admin but it returning an error.

**Query**:

```sql
Select 
   'databases' as category,
   count(*) as found, 
   '3' as expected
from SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES
where DATABASE_NAME IN ('USDA_NUTRIENT_STDREF','LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG','SOCIAL_MEDIA_FLOODGATES')
```

**Error**:

> SQL compilation error: Database 'SNOWFLAKE' does not exist or not authorized.

Checked SNOWFLAKE database exists but it does not have any schema including INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: Does the database user have permission to access the information_schema ?

Comment: are you sure you're running this as the `accountadmin` role? This worked for me as `sysadmin`

Comment: Note that you don't have to run this query against the SNOWFLAKE database. If you run it against any database, it will return the same results. If it doesn't work when using SNOWFLAKE, see what happens when you try another database.

Answer (score 2):

Databases live under your account. Account is the top level object in the Snowflake object hierarchy. Databases live under account. See [this link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html), and find the text where it says, "The top-most container is the customer account...". It's got a nice little graphic there.

When you query information_schema on the Snowflake database, you're getting the information_schema of just the snowflake database, not of your entire account. Snowflake.information_schema is kinda useless b/c it just shows the information schema of a database (Snowflake) that you have no control over - Snowflake controls it.

If you want to see all the databases in your account, you can do the following:

```
use role accountadmin;
show databases;
select count(*) from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "name" in ('USDA_NUTRIENT_STDREF','LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG','SOCIAL_MEDIA_FLOODGATES');
```

Now, separately, if you're concerned about the error you're getting - that you don't have access to the snowflake database, then I'd say you're either not using the accountadmin role, or you're not using a role that has the right privileges. If you'd like to give a role privileges to the Snowlfake database, you can run the following:

```
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES
    ON DATABASE SNOWFLAKE TO ROLE {SOME_ROLE_OF_YOURS};
```

Good luck!